# Eclipse crashing in PyDev with No Message gotten (null message)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, eclipse-luna

I use Eclipse Luna with PyDev for Eclipse 4.0.0.201504132356.

My function returns a list, which is a list of objects from one class.

So i use it like this:

```
List = ListMaker()    
print List[0].Stuff.Stuff
```

and this works(!); i see exactly what should be in the list.

However, when making a new new line of code and writing:

*List[0].*
i get immediately a Problem Occured Message:

> No Message gotten (null message)
>
> Java.lang.StackOverflowError

which is clearly wrong; since i see the output is fine and simply clicking the message away. I used the same project in Visual Studio with Python Tools for Visual Studio and never had this Problem either.

Clicking this message away is although pretty annoying. Does someone know how to fix this?

EDIT: The error occures in `org.python.pydev.shared_core`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I upgraded to Pydev 4.1.0 and it was resolved.
http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html
The the list of fixes that went in 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This really seems like some recursion issue on the type inference analysis for PyDev.

Can you please report that as a bug at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ so that I can take a look to fix it?

If you could create a github repo with sources where I can reproduce the issue, that'd be awesome.

Also, your error log probably contains the stack trace where this happened... At http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F there are instructions on how to get it (please include that in the bug report).

Comment: Ok i will do all that, but I'll not have to time to do it until the weekend;